# How to store rrweb-io events in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I tried the following options
- convert the events to string and store them in a text filed
- store the events in a JSON field
they both did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events array was too big to be stored, so instead of storing it in a database
I stored it in file and stored the file path in the database :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to create model and you it for save in database

Comment: model?
I have a node js api that receives the request, the problem is when storing them in the mysql database. I keep having an error